# Why does $().map Produces Circular Reference

Tags: javascript, jquery

Chrome's `array.map` works fine, but jQuery's `.map` produces a circular reference somehow.  I can't see any evidence of a circular reference using `console.log`, but JSON.stringify throws `Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON` in the second block.

Run it on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/langdonx/vQBak/

Or check the code:

```
var callback = function(index, element) {
    return {
        "index": index
    };
};

var array1 = ["1", "2"];
var mappedArray1 = array1.map(callback);
console.log(mappedArray1);
var json1 = JSON.stringify(mappedArray1);
console.log(json1);

var jqueryArray2 = $('body > div');
var mappedArray2 = jqueryArray2.map(callback);
console.log(mappedArray2);
var json2 = JSON.stringify(mappedArray2); // Chokes with "Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"
console.log(json2);​
```

Yes, I'm using the same callback, and yes ECMAScript's `map` passes the arguments in a different order, but it shouldn't matter for this example, as they're all simple types (string, number).

Comment: Not sure if it is relevant, but the `.map()` callback has parameters `(element, index, array)` not `(index, element)`

Comment: Does `JSON.stringify($('body > div'))` produce a circular reference error?  Maybe jQuery objects just have circular references.

Comment: @apsillers yes - you always get a circular reference if you try to serialize a jQuery object.

Comment: (@Pointy - Thanks; I would have tested it myself but I'm on a mobile device, where it's much faster to speculate than test.)

Comment: @jbabey I'm using .map, not $.map.  Also, you missed the note at the bottom. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The jQuery [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) function returns a jQuery object containing an array, not an actual array, which may be an important difference. Try calling:

```
var json2 = JSON.stringify(mappedArray2.get());
```

The call to `.get()` will return the actual array rather than a jQuery object.

Comment: He is using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) not [map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) - nevermind, i see what you did there.

Comment: @jbabey: He's using different maps in the different examples

Comment: So how is it possible to know this?  `console.log(mappedArray1);` and `console.log(mappedArray2);` are identical in the Chrome console.  As well, they are both `typeof` object.  If I'm getting an array back from a library that's not mine, how can I detect if it's a JavaScript array or a jQuery array during troubleshooting?

Comment: @Langdon Other than reading the documentation? I don't think there's an easy way to programmatically determine that; I suppose you could attempt to use a jQuery function inside a try/catch block.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist ah, true, feature detection should work, thanks.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Orrr I can just use `console.dir` instead of `console.log` in Chrome.